# How to add Track changes option in ckeditor 5 in react?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, ckeditor5

I want to use Track changes options in ckeditor 5 in my react project.

I went through the documentation here

[cheditor5 track changes](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/collaboration/comments/comments-integration.html)

I didn't get the clear idea here.

So these are the steps that I have done

step 1 : From [here](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) created on-line build for track changes option

step-2 : Downloaded zip file and copied build/ckeditor.js file to my react node modules ckeditor classic build ckeditor.js file

step 3 :added code like this

```
<CKEditor
           editor={ClassicEditor}
            config={{
           toolbar:['bold','trackChanges']
         }}
          data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>" />
```

But when I preview on the browser Its showing bold and track changes in ckeditor but its showing it as disabled.

So how to I add track changes option ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This option is not free, you need to buy it or wait for LITE support for CKEditor V5.

Currently, LITE support CKEditor Version 4 but if you want to use Version 5 I think you need to wait for LITE update.

Track Changes pricing : https://ckeditor.com/collaboration/track-changes/

LITE Web site : https://www.loopindex.com/track-changes/